# facebook share page can't show &(ampersand) mark?

Tags: facebook-sharer, ampersand, rich-snippets

in facebook sharer page, it can show title including & mark
ex:

```
url to share: http://myhome.com?q=hi&there
```

title tag of this page is

```
<title>hi&amp;there</title>
```

But, actually, facebook sharer page shows 
title: hi
link: http://myhome.com?q=hi

I call the API like below.
"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + "&t=" + encodeURIComponent(document.title)
and I tried to use Open graph meta tag(og:title, og:url), but it does not help.

I checked my url in facebook developer's debug site(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).
but in debug site, it printed right title and link (including ampersand sign)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your ampersand is encoded in your original url, otherwise it acts as a delimiter between variables.

Assuming your app echoes the value in the `q` query string as its title, a url like you show: `http://myhome.com?q=hi&there` returns two variables: 'q' = 'hi' and 'there' = 1.

Your URL should have the literal `&` encoded: `http://myhome.com?q=hi%26there` to return 'q' = 'hi&there'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php encode any url string like

```
<? echo urlencode("http://myhome.com?q=hi"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

By the question above, I guess that hardcoding the url exactly like it should be and pass it to the sharer api is not an option.

**The problem:**

As you may have noticed, facebook (and g+ also) will not accept the '&' character as well as anything that follows that.

So we should find a way to decode ONLY this '&'.

If you use encodeURIComponent then, **all** you url's special characters will be transformed to '%xx' style.

I.E.

```
var url_enc = encodeURIComponent('http://myhome.com?q=hi&there');
alert(url_enc);
```

will output this: `http%3A%2F%2Fmyhome.com%3Fq%3Dhi%26there`

which is not accepted by sharer either!

As I wrote before, what is really needed here is to send a url like this:

```
http://myhome.com?q=hi%26there
```

which is accepted by facebook api.

**Solution:**

If you can't send the url as it is, and it maybe needs to be passed through a library that creates sharers and does the job for you, you need to pass exactly the url as it should be and then combine encodeURI and decodeURIComponent like below. (Personally i had to make this correction in order to work fine, so it was a serious bug)

In the following example, i assume that a javascript library is used.

```
var url = 'http://myhome.com?q=hi%26there';
library_function_that_creates_sharer(some_variable, url);
```

and then, inside that function, encode and decode to keep the url exactly the same.

```
decodeURIComponent(encodeURI(url));
```

In other words:

```
var url_new = decodeURIComponent(encodeURI(url));
```

ends up to be `url_new = url`.